# Vegetable factory

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to build a simple hierarchy of classes.

```
abstract class Vegetable
{
    public Vegetable(double weight)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
        ...
    }

    ...
}

class Tomato extends Vegetable
{
    public Tomato(double weight)
    {
            super(weight);
        ...

    }
    ...
}

class Cucumber extends Vegetable
{
    public Cucumber(double weight)
    {
            super(weight);
        ...

    }
    ...
}
```

I have some abstract methods in class `Vegetable`, which are overridden in `Tomato` and `Cucumber`.
I want to implement logic of buying vegetables. I've created the following class for it:

```
public class VegetableFactory
{
    public static ArrayList<Vegetable> buy(int num, Class vegetableClass)
    {
        ArrayList<Vegetable> res = new ArrayList<Vegetable>(num);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            double weight = (Math.random() * 200) + 100;
            Vegetable v = null;
            try
            {
                v = (Vegetable) vegetableClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Double.TYPE).newInstance(weight);
            } catch (InstantiationException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            res.add(v);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Is it a good way of doing that? And is it ideologically correct to name it factory? Any suggestions of improvement are highly appreciated.

Comment: I would use dictionary instead of switch look at this question my answer
[Factory design pattern](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/is-this-correct-factory-method-pattern/5755#comment8705_5755)

Comment: I take exception to both tomatoes and cucumbers being classified as vegetables ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use an enum type instead of having to pass a class in. This way, it's impossible to pass something bad in, and you can catch errors at compile time instead of runtime.

```
enum VegetableType { CARROT, TOMATO, CUCUMBER };
```

Then your buy method would be simply

```
static ArrayList<Vegetable> buy(int num, VegetableType vegType) {
    ArrayList<Vegetable> veggies = new ArrayList<Vegetable>(n); //n is the initial capacity - size is still zero.
    for(int i=0; i < num; ++i) {
        double weight = (Math.random() * 200) + 100;

        switch(vegType) {
        case VegetableType.CARROT:
            veggies.add(new Carrot(weight));
            break;
        case VegetableType.TOMATO:
            veggies.add(new Tomato(weight));
            break;
        case VegetableType.CUCMBER:
            veggies.add(new Cucumber(weight));
            break;
        }
    }
    return veggies;
 }
```

Now of course the problem is that you end up having a big `switch` statement in the middle in your loop. Generally, while ugly I'd say that this is sufficient - you get some more control over each of the individual constructors, so you're not constrained to the same set of parameters.

The other thing that you could do is have a factory method on the `VegetableType` to create an instance:

```
enum VegetableType {
    CARROT { Vegetable createInstance(int weight) { return new Carrot(weight); }},
    TOMATO { Vegetable createInstance(int weight) { return new Tomato(weight); } },
    CUCUMBER { Vegetable createInstance(int weight) { return new Cucumber(weight); } };

    abstract Vegetable createInstance(int weight);
}
```

Then your list becomes

```
static ArrayList<Vegetable> buy(int num, VegetableType vegType) {
    ArrayList<Vegetable> veggies = new ArrayList<Vegetable>();
    for(int i=0; i < num; ++i) {
        double weight = (Math.random() * 200) + 100;
        veggies.add(vegType.createInstance(weight));
    }
    return veggies;
 }
```

Finally, if you want to get fancy, `java.lang.reflect` has the `Constructor` class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html

You can then use this to get the constructor to the `Vegetable` type of your choice, and then call construct repeatedly in the loop.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it a good way of doing that?

No. Give more thought about the *separation of concerns* for each class. The buy logic does not belong in a factory. A factory is only for creating the various veggie types. `Buy` should be in a `VegetableStand` class or perhaps in the `Vegetable` class.

If "buying" logic is unique per vegetable then put buy() in the `Vegetable` class - especially if it also has a `price` property. Even so, I can see a `VegetableCart.Buy()` that accumulates everything into a "bag" so the different veggies, quantities, and prices can be added - for a total price to the customer.

> And is it ideologically correct to name it factory?

Not the way you've written it. A veggie factory is for creating various veggies. I expect to see a `create()` method, passing in an enum as suggested above.

```
public class VegetableStand {
    VeggieFactory myVF = new VeggieFactory();

    public ArrayList<Vegetable> bag = new ArrayList<Vegetable>;

    public ArrayList<Vegetable> Buy (VegetableType whatKind ,int howMany){
        for (int i=0, i<howMany; i++) {
            bag.add(myVF.Create(whatKind);
        }
    }

    public double TotalSale (ArrayList<Vegetable> bag) {
        double totalPrice = new double;

        foreach (Vegetable item in Bag) {
             totalPrice += item.Price;
         }

       return totalPrice;
    }
}

internal class VeggieFactory {
    public static Vegetable Create(VegetableType whatKind) {
        Vegetable thisKind;

        switch(whatKind) {
            case: VegetableType.carrot
                thisKind = CreateCarrot();
                break;
            case: VegetableType.cucumber
                thisKind = CreateCucumber();
                break;
            default:
               throw new Veggie not invented yet exception;
        }
        return thisKind;
    }
}
```

Then, in the `buy()` method you should not have a big `switch` statement in the `for` loop. If you're passing in a veggie instance, that doesn't make sense. If you already created that veggie, why the factory?

- You should separate the creation of the `ArrayList<Vegetable>` from the creation of the vegetables themselves. The `buy()` method creates a new list for every veggie you buy. And, you may want to instantiate a veggie w/o a list.

Comment: Would it make sense in this case you pass the `VeggieFactory` into the `VegetableStand` via the constructor to decouple them?

Comment: @Supericy, doesn't hurt, if I expected the factory design to evolve such that there will be various kinds of VeggieFactory then absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

As far I see nobody pointed out yet that the reference type of the list should be only `List`. Instead of

```
ArrayList<Vegetable> res = new ArrayList<Vegetable>(num);
```

use

```
List<Vegetable> res = new ArrayList<Vegetable>(num);
```

The signature of the method also should be changed:

```
public static List<Vegetable> buy(int num, Class vegetableClass)
```

[Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what's already been said, when dealing with `Class`, you should use type boundaries to eliminate the possibility of receiving something you weren't expecting:

```
public static <T extends Vegetable> ArrayList<Vegetable> buy(int num, Class<T> vegetableClass)
```

And then:

```
v = (T) vegetableClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Double.TYPE).newInstance(weight);
```